# How to save/load model with intermediate outputs

Tags: python, keras

I'm writting autoencoder in Keras:

```
inputs = Input((n_channels,))
l1 = Dense(40, activation="relu")(inputs)
l2 = Dense(19)(l1)
l3 = Dense(40, activation="relu")(l2)
training_layer = Dense(n_channels)(l3)
unify_layer = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=l2)
training_layer = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=training_layer)
```

I use `training_layer` for training, and `unify_layer` for predicting, so when I continue learning after saving it, I'd like to have access to both endpoints.

[Edit due to Marcin's comment]`Model.save` allows me save only one model. When I call:

```
unify_layer.save("unify")
training_layer.save("training")
```

And then

```
unify_layer = load_model("unify")
training_layer = load_model("training")
```

Two layer are no more linked i.e. when I train `training_layer`, `unify_layer` isn't trained.

Comment: What do you mean by `model.save` allowing only one model?

Answer (score 3):

Oh, I actually can use `save_weights` and `load_weights` method:

```
class Autoencoder():
    def __init__(self):
        inputs = Input((n_channels,))
        l1 = Dense(40, activation="relu")(inputs)
        l2 = Dense(19)(l1)
        l3 = Dense(40, activation="relu")(l2)
        training_layer = Dense(n_channels)(l3)
        self.unify_layer = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=l2)
        self.training_layer = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=training_layer)

    def save(self, filename):
        self.unify_layer.save_weights("unify_" + filename)
        self.training_layer.save_weights("training_" + filename)

    def load(self, filename):
        self.unify_layer.load_weights("unify_" + filename)
        self.training_layer.load_weights("training_" + filename)
```